# Updating RibbonMenu

Tags: .net, vsto, ribbon, ribbon-control, ribbonx

I'm trying to find a way to update a RibbonMenu's items (like a few RibbonButtons) *when the RibbonMenu is clicked* (i.e. something like a *BeforeDropDown*). I know I can update it with the event of another control, but how do it update it when it is clicked?

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonmenu) doesn't seem to be of much help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your menu is set to `Dynamic = True` and then use the RibbonMenu's `ItemsLoading` event. This will allow you to capture what happens to the what's dropped down before it's dropped down.

Comment: Is it possible to update the Controls in a RibbonMenu while its already open? I have tried, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: In my tests, the `ItemsLoading` event occurs for the first and sometimes for the second time when the users clicks the RibbonMenu button. After that, the event does _not_ occur anymore, no matter how often the users clicks the RibbonMenu button. Even when having the `Dynamic = True` set.